# Can't pass a value ajax to servlet

Tags: java, ajax, servlets

I have a simple code here,

```
$.ajax({
        url: "updateAccount",
        type: "POST",
        data:  {username : "username",pasword:"pasw" , Id : "123"},
        success: function(response) {
            if (response === "success") {
                alert("update success");
                location.href = "account.jsp";
                loadData();
            } else {
                alert("update fail");
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("execute fail");
        }
    });
```

but in my servlet:

```
if (userPath.equals("/updateAccount")) {
    String id = request.getParameter("Id");
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    AccountDTO accountDTO = new AccountDTO();
    //accountDTO.setId(id);
    accountDTO.setUsername(username);
    accountDTO.setPassword(password);
    out.print(accountBS.updateAccount(accountDTO));
}
```

I just only get the value of Id, and username. Value of the parameter `password = null`.Why and how can i get all of id,username,password values.

Comment: You're looking for a parameter called `"password"`, but passing one called `"pasword"`.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the code as follows, Spelling mistake for the key password

```
data:  {username : "username",password:"pasw" , Id : "123"}
```